# matplotlib graph not showing inside pyscript tag in html code

Tags: python, html, matplotlib, web-development-server, pyscript

Can anyone give the details of how can i run and display my matplotlib figure in html page using pyscript , please mentions all the installations required because i tried printing text it worked but figure generated using matplotlib in python is not getting displayed [on running code inside tag <pyscript>](https://i.stack.imgur.com/1SCUJ.png)

```
<html>
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <meta name="viewport"
          content="width=device-width, user-scalable=no, initial-scale=1.0, maximum-scale=1.0, minimum-scale=1.0">
    <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="ie=edge">
    <title>Document</title>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://pyscript.net/latest/pyscript.css" />
    <script defer src="https://pyscript.net/latest/pyscript.js"></script>


    <py-env>
        -matplotlib
    </py-env>
</head>
<body>
    <h1>Matplotlib</h1>
    <div id="lineplot"></div>
    <py-script output="lineplot">
        import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
        fig, ax = plt.subplots()

        year_1 = [2016, 2017, 2018, 2019, 2020, 2021]
        population_1 = [42, 43, 45, 47, 48, 50]

        year_2 = [2016, 2017, 2018, 2019, 2020, 2021]
        population_2 = [43, 43, 44, 44, 45, 45]

        plt.plot(year_1, population_1, marker='o', linestyle='--', color='g', label='Country 1')
        plt.plot(year_2, population_2,  marker='d', linestyle='-', color='r', label='Country 2')

        plt.xlabel('Year')
        plt.ylabel('Population (M)')
        plt.title('Year vs Population')
        plt.legend(loc='lower right')

        fig
    </py-script>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Please copy the error text into the Question.

Answer (score 1):

**Pyscript changes very fast.** As noted [here](https://twitter.com/JeffersGlass/status/1634205554846343170) by Jeff Glass:

> "No longer in alpha, though there are still big changes coming with every release."

You have to put in effort to keep up with it. What you posted uses outdated syntax.

I would suggest a recent resource by Jeff Glass [from where I quoted above for getting started](https://twitter.com/JeffersGlass/status/1625503072939315212):
that [video on youtube](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=wFvr14tNoVw).

#### They have a Matplotlib example you can adapt

Importantly for you, there is an offered Matplotlib example among those listed on [the Pyscript demos page](https://pyscript.net/examples/). It is found **presently** under the 'MIME Rendering' section [there](https://pyscript.net/examples/), which is below the 'Basic examples' and above the 'JS Interaction' section:

- link to 'Matplotlib' pyscript example running served on web: [here](https://pyscript.net/examples/matplotlib.html)
- link to the code for 'Matplotlib' pyscript example on Github: [here](https://github.com/pyscript/pyscript/blob/main/examples/matplotlib.html)

(I note that also on the ['Getting started with PyScript' page](https://docs.pyscript.net/latest/tutorials/getting-started.html), there is a more streamlined matplotlib example you could adapt.)

Adapting your code to the current Pyscript Matplotlib example:

- See the adapted version running on the web [here](https://fomightez.github.io/pyscript_test/another_plot_example.html).
- The adapted code:

```html
<html>
 <!-- dcoument based on:
- https://pyscript.net/examples/matplotlib.html and adapting to https://stackoverflow.com/q/76014723/8508004

-->
    <head>
        <title>Matplotlib - from https://pyscript.net/examples/matplotlib.html April 2023</title>
        <meta charset="utf-8" />
        <link rel="icon" type="image/x-icon" href="https://pyscript.net/examples/favicon.png" />
        <link
            rel="stylesheet"
            href="https://pyscript.net/latest/pyscript.css"
        />
        <script defer src="https://pyscript.net/latest/pyscript.js"></script>
        <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://pyscript.net/examples/assets/css/examples.css" />
    </head>
    <body>
        <nav class="navbar" style="background-color: #000000">
            <div class="app-header">
                <a href="/">
                    <img src="https://pyscript.net/examples/logo.png" class="logo" />
                </a>
                <a class="title" href="" style="color: #f0ab3c">Matplotlib</a>
            </div>
        </nav>
        <section class="pyscript">
            <div id="mpl"></div>

            <py-tutor>
                <py-config>
                    packages = [
                      "matplotlib"
                    ]
                    plugins = [
                      "https://pyscript.net/latest/plugins/python/py_tutor.py"
                    ]
                </py-config>

                <py-script>
                    import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
                    fig, ax = plt.subplots()
                    
                    year_1 = [2016, 2017, 2018, 2019, 2020, 2021]
                    population_1 = [42, 43, 45, 47, 48, 50]
                    
                    year_2 = [2016, 2017, 2018, 2019, 2020, 2021]
                    population_2 = [43, 43, 44, 44, 45, 45]
                    
                    plt.plot(year_1, population_1, marker='o', linestyle='--', color='g', label='Country 1')
                    plt.plot(year_2, population_2,  marker='d', linestyle='-', color='r', label='Country 2')
                    
                    plt.xlabel('Year')
                    plt.ylabel('Population (M)')
                    plt.title('Year vs Population')
                    plt.legend(loc='lower right')

                    display(fig, target="mpl")
                </py-script>
            </py-tutor>
        </section>
    </body>
</html>
```

You can run that right here by clicking the 'Run code snippet' button; I found I needed to then click on 'Full page' view option that will then come up on the right side in order to see the plot. You can get back to the post by clicking on 'Close' in the upper right from the full page view.)

Comment: Glad the video is proving a useful introduction. Thanks Wayne!